# Postgres service does not restart after windows server restart

Tags: postgresql

I have postgres 8.3 installed on windows server 2003.
The postgres service is not started after windows server restart.
Its startup type is automatic.

I have to set log on password again in service properties and restart the service manually.

Does anyone has the same problem? How do you resolve this?

Comment: Have a look in the PostgreSQL log to see if for some reason it does start but aborts.

Comment: Also take a look at the event log.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you have to run the postgres service with the user "postgres", which is usually set up when you install it. Try changing the service to run with account "postgres".

If you are already doing that, check the permissions of the postgres account.

Comment: It's running with postgres. What permissions are required?